# TimelineView stops updating

Tags: swift, swiftui

For some reason after the first time I tap the Indulge button the UI stops updating. The indulgences array count stops incrementing and the computed property pctIntervalComplete stops updating.

```
struct Habit: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Habit, rhs: Habit) -> Bool {
        return lhs.habitId == rhs.habitId
    }
    
    public let habitId: UUID
    public var habitName: String
    public var indulgences: [Indulgence]
    
    public var daysInterval: Int
    public var hoursInterval: Int
    public var minsInterval: Int
    public var secsInterval: Int
    public var daysIncrease: Int
    public var hoursIncrease: Int
    public var minsIncrease: Int
    public var secsIncrease: Int
    
    private let minutesToSeconds: Int = 60
    private let hoursToSeconds: Int = 3600
    private let daysToSeconds: Int = 86400
    
    public var pctIntervalComplete: Double {
        guard let latestIndulgence = indulgences.last else {
            return 0.0
        }
        
        let currentInterval = Date.now.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - latestIndulgence.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        
        return currentInterval / targetIntervalInSeconds
    }
    
    public var isIntervalComplete: Bool {
        return pctIntervalComplete >= 1.0
    }
    
    private var targetIntervalInSeconds: TimeInterval {
        return TimeInterval((daysInterval * daysToSeconds) + (hoursInterval * hoursToSeconds) + (minsInterval * minutesToSeconds) + secsInterval)
    }
    
    init(habitId: UUID = UUID(), habitName: String) {
        self.habitId = habitId
        self.habitName = habitName
        indulgences = [Indulgence]()
        daysInterval = 0
        hoursInterval = 0
        minsInterval = 1
        secsInterval = 0
        daysIncrease = 0
        hoursIncrease = 0
        minsIncrease = 1
        secsIncrease = 0
    }
    
    mutating public func addIndulgence() {
        var i = Indulgence(habitId: self.habitId)
        indulgences.append(i)
    }
}

struct Indulgence: Hashable {
    public let indulgenceId: UUID
    public let habitId: UUID
    public let timestamp: Date

    init(indulgenceId: UUID = UUID(), habitId: UUID, timestamp: Date = Date.now) {
        self.indulgenceId = indulgenceId
        self.habitId = habitId
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}

struct HabitListView: View {
    @State private var habitList = [Habit(habitName: "Habit 1"), Habit(habitName: "Habit 2")]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($habitList, id: \.habitId) { $habit in
                HStack{
                    Text(habit.habitName)
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Indulge") {
                        habit.addIndulgence() //only works once
                    }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                        .tint(habit.isIntervalComplete ? .pink : .gray)
                    
                    TimelineView(.periodic(from: Date.now, by: 1)) { _ in
                        CircularProgressView(progress: habit.pctIntervalComplete) //stops updating
                            .frame(maxHeight: 36)
                            .scaleEffect(0.35)
                        
                        Text("\(habit.indulgences.count)") //stops incrementing
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct CircularProgressView: View {
    let progress: Double
    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 7
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(
                    Color.pink.opacity(0.5),
                    lineWidth: lineWidth
                )
                
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0, to: progress)
                .stroke(
                    Color.pink,
                    style: StrokeStyle(
                        lineWidth: lineWidth,
                        lineCap: .round
                    )
                )
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
                .animation(.easeOut, value: progress)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lying to the compiler by providing your own `Equatable` conformance:

```
static func == (lhs: Habit, rhs: Habit) -> Bool {
  return lhs.habitId == rhs.habitId
}
```

By doing this, you're telling it that any `Habit` that has the same `habitId` is completely equal. This is not true -- they are not equal if they have different properties (such as number of `indulgences`).

Remove this and it will work.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks! Does TimelineView compare a snapshot of the variables to the current values, run an equality check and if equal, not update?

Comment: Watch Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC for info about equality. In general, a `View` will _never_ update if it is equal to the version currently in the tree.